# function composition with reverse syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax, function-composition

If I want to apply `f` first and `g` second, I have to write:

```
g . f
```

Is there another standard syntax that would allow me to write the functions in the reverse order?

```
f <whatever> g
```

I know I can just invent my own syntax:

```
compose f g x = g (f x)
```

and then use it like this:

```
f `compose` g
```

But I would rather use a standard library facility.

Comment: I just defined `(.>) = flip (.)`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`f >>> g` from [Control.Arrow](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Control-Arrow.html).

Comment: Thanks, the change from `.` to `>>>` really made my particular piece of code much easier to understand :) By the way, I'm not too familiar with arrows, but I take it `>>>` is much more general than `.`, right?

Comment: I was hoping this would show up if I Hoogled "(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c". Alas, Hoogle is not quite clever enough.

Comment: @FredOverflow: `<<<` and `>>>` are defined for the `Category` class, which is indeed more general. All `Arrow` instances are `Category` instances, including the familiar `(->)`. On the other hand, the whole point of `Arrow` and `Category` is to generalize things that compose end-to-end given matching types, like functions do, so you don't need to worry too much about `Arrow`s as a whole here.

Comment: @Daniel Pratt: Alas, Hoogle won't match `(->)` against type constructor variables. It won't find anything for `(a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, either.

Comment: @C. A. McCann: It's probably a result of the special treatment `(->)` gets with respect to reordering of arguments and so on. It's able to generalize other type constructor operators.

Comment: Neat, I guess, but I'd really rather not deal with all of the extra machinery of a category. I'll just define it myself, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In addtition to [`>>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208611/915552), some libraries provide their own version of this function, for example:

- `compose` or `.>` from [Flow](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/flow-2.0.0.0/docs/Flow.html#v:compose).
- `-.`from [composition-prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-prelude-3.0.0.2/docs/Control-Composition.html#v:-45-.).

You may use [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) to find examples of functions with a specific signature. For your exact question you can use [hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20b)%20-%3E%20(b%20-%3E%20c)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20c)).